# JQuery Upgrade and AJAX

Tags: ajax, post, jquery

I just upgraded to JQuery 1.5.2 from 1.4 and my PostForm is not working now . It does post to page but even though there is no error it says there is error.

```
function TestPostForm(){
               $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "process.jsp",
                    data: 'operation=Test&ui=TestUser',
                    dataType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    async: false,
                    success: function(response) {
                        alert('Success');
                        return response;                    
                     },
                         error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                              alert("There was an error : " + xhr.status);
                       }
                    });
              }
```

Java Code : process.jsp

```
if (operation.equals("Test")) {
            String ui = request.getParameter("ui");
            out.println("Ok" + ui);
        }
```

Comment: what is the `out` var. does it get echoed back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with `dataType`, what you should have defined was `contentTypeString`:

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

`dataType` defines what type of data you expect your script to return (xml, json, script or html) while `contentType` passes the type of content you are sending in the request.

You can read more about these options on the jQuery API: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

why not send data this way?

`data: {'operation': 'Test', 'ui': 'TestUser'}` Yo don't need to specify `dataType` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Sniff your AJAX activity using Firebug and see what error is being generated on your server. This may give you a clue.